# How should the transition from tile to carpet be done?

Tags: flooring

How should the transition from tile to carpet be done?  What do we need to use?

We just had all our flooring replaced, but by three different crews, and now we have unfinished transitions.

We had the linoleum in our kitchen and baths replaced with tile first, but they left the edges of the areas rugged, and told us the carpet people would install a transition of some sort.  Also note, the tile was installed on top of plywood and 1/2 in backer board which caused the tile floor to be higher than the other flooring areas.  The carpet people came (HD) and told us they don't install the transitions, that the tile person should have done it and it requires a special tile glue.

So, what do we need to get exactly and who will we need to install it?  We have one wooden transition from kitchen to hall where we had hard wood installed.  But nothing anywhere else through out the house between medium types, and we know it's not right but don't know what to do.  It is especially bad because the hard surfaces are a bit higher than the carpeted areas and thus very noticeable to sight and touch.

Also, shouldn't all the transition areas match throughout the house?  We already have one strip of oak T-shape? Where the kitchen tile goes to hardwood in the hall/foyer, but it doesn't look like this type of stripping is made to go where tile and carpet meet (which are the other two sides of the kitchen).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKsUO.jpg)[image][image][image]

Comment: Why can't you use molding similar to your last photo?  If the floors are not at the same height [reducer transitions](https://onflooring.com/sites/default/files/pictures/105-RD.jpg) are available.

Comment: See the picture at the bottom of [my answer here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51779/is-it-ok-to-use-1-4-concrete-backer-board-over-1-2-plywood-as-a-bathroom-subfl). Personally, I wouldn't use a transition there (nice job on the carpet).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like [wood transitions](http://www.homedepot.com/p/TrafficMASTER-36-in-Tile-to-Carpet-Hardwood-Transition-18500/202066504) here is an example that HD has. I think wood looks better than the metal ones but metal is a little easier to install [aluminum transition](http://www.homedepot.com/p/M-D-Building-Products-Satin-Clear-1-263-in-x-96-in-Aluminum-Tile-to-Carpet-Edging-Trim-07567/205877123). I have had the carpet guys install the transitions they usually have the good ones that lock the edge of the carpet in place I did not see that style when I was looking at the aluminum.