# can I install cement backer board over plank subfloor

Tags: tile, underlayment, cement-board, thinset

I have old plank subfloor installed at a 45 degree angle to the floor joists.
[image]How should I install cbu(cement backer board) on top of this for a tile installation?

The entire area is approximately four feet by four feet.
the joist are 2 inches by 9 inches by 11 feet

Comment: I have put down backer directly on t&g, if the t&g is not totally flat I put some thinset down prior to screwing it down and have never had any problems even with large living spaces +16x 24 on the last one I did for my last house on the 2nd floor living room.

Comment: this is not tongue-and-groove, it’s butt-jointed (the straight-cut planks are laid next to each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is no, too much bounce. Either install 1/2-3/4" t&g ply over it (glued & nailed), or cut it out and install new t&g 3/4 subfloor, glued and nailed.

Also consider your floor joist width and span. In this question, that's undetermined.

In either case, then you can install 1/2" cement board.

Comment: I have updated my questions to include the floors dimensions. 
 However the joists are a little complex i am going to simplify it and say that there is a 15 inch average span

Comment: I mean the length span. I think you are talking about the spacing between the joists. Can you re-edit the OP? You omitted one of the measurements.

Comment: the length is 11 feet

Comment: Oh, little tiny thing. No worries, put down the cement board and start layin. Maybe to be sure, set the board in a bed of thinset with a 1/4" notched trowel.

Comment: I see that the real question is a different then the one i asked. I will re-ask the question.  I am looking for a source to your last comment.

Comment: Must be getting something lost in translation, sorry about that. I'm saying - If the total area is only 4'x4', go ahead and lay your cement board down and set some tile. That area should be plenty stiff to support the tilework.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. however, i saw on http://www.johnbridge.com forum not to treat a smaller area differently then a larger one.

Comment: That's a "cya" thing, not to be confused with real-life.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all brands specify minimum 5/8" plywood or OSB as a base.

I have to say, if it was my house and there were **significant** challenges related to plywood installation (plank removal difficult, heigh problem with plywood over plank, etc.) I might consider mortaring and screwing it down without the plywood if and only if the plank subfloor was *very* sturdy (no flex/bounce/deflection when jumped up and down on) and *very* flat.

Comment: Its not very flat. It is very sturdy.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51779/is-it-ok-to-use-1-4-concrete-backer-board-over-1-2-plywood-as-a-bathroom-subfl/51787#51787

Answer (score 0):

fasten any loose planks and flatten (plane, sand, chisel) any planks that are not level

1/2 inch - 3/4 inch exterior rated plywood or osb, screwed down to the planks the screws should avoid hitting the joists

thinset applied with 1/4 inch x 1/4 inch trowel applied on top of the plywood/osb

1/2 inch cement backer board on top of the thinset and screwed in just after the thinset is applied. it's O.K. to walk on the cement board before the thinset sets

Comment: I am just adding to NPM's answer